# Cypher left outer join sql analog

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to match all nodes with specific label that has no relationship **or** have specific relationship. something like this two queries combined:

```
MATCH (f:Field) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (f)--(t:Type) 
WHERE id(t) = {id} RETURN f
+
MATCH (f:Field) 
WHERE not (f)--(:Type) 
RETURN f
```

Something like this:

```
MATCH (f:Field),(t:Type) 
WHERE id(t) = {id} 
AND NOT (f)--(:Type) 
OR (f)--(t)
RETURN f, id(t) 
ORDER BY id(t) 
LIMIT 10
```

but this never ends to execute with 150k of `:Field`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something like this two queries **combined**:

You can simply use a [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/union/). The UNION docs says:

> The **UNION** clause is used **to combine** the result of multiple queries.

Try it:

```
MATCH (f:Field) OPTIONAL MATCH (f)--(t:Type) WHERE id(t) = {id} RETURN f
UNION
MATCH (f:Field) WHERE not (f)--(:Type) RETURN f
```

Or you can try changing the second Cypher query to:

```
// First match 't' where t.id = {id}
MATCH (t:Type)
WHERE id(t) = {id}
// After match f when (f)--(t) or not (f)--(:Type)
MATCH (f:Field)
WHERE (f)--(t)
OR
NOT (f)--(:Type) 
// return desired data
RETURN f, id(t) ORDER BY id(t) LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
MATCH (f:Field)
OPTIONAL MATCH (f)--(t:Type)
WITH f, t
WHERE t = null OR id(t) = {id} 
RETURN f
```

By using a WHERE after a WITH instead of after the OPTIONAL MATCH, we allow it to filter the rows we need, instead of filtering on the OPTIONAL MATCH.